# Windows Batch: reg query key value to a variable but do not display error if key doesn't exist

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch command that fetches a registry key and assigns value to a variable but it displays error when the key doesn't exist

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\MySoftware\1.0\MyExecutable /v "InstallDir" ^| findstr InstallDir') do set InstallPath=%%b
```

Is there a way to bypass the exception? I have tried using **2>NUL** after the reg query or at the end of the command but I get an exception **2> was unexpected at this time.**

help/ guidance much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should solve the problem like with the pipe. `^|`
Simply escape it to `2^>NUL`

So you get

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\MySoftware\1.0\MyExecutable /v "InstallDir" 2^>NUL ^| findstr InstallDir') do set InstallPath=%%b
```

It's neccessary because the command part of the FOR-Loop will be parsed two times.
First in the context of your batch file (there the 2>NUL is unexpected), and the second time in the new cmd.exe context (there the 2>NUL redirects the stderr of your `reg` command)

Comment: Doh! i didn't think of the escape character. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Note that this method only works if the value you look for does not have a space in its name. Assume there's a value named `Product Version` then the `for /f "tokens=2,*"` would become confused.

Comment: @Tomalak You are right, but then you know how many spaces your value contain and you can change the `tokens=2,*` to `tokens=2+<space>,*`

Comment: It always boils down to: Doing basic stuff in batch files is difficult, doing anything remotely advanced is a pain in the ass. Nice addition, though.

Comment: Funny thing is, I thought of the escape char but I pre-constructed the command to execute in an environment variable. When you do this, you need to double-escape (^^^>) in the variable, so that an escaped redirection shows up in the for command. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Additionally, you don't need to findstr the right line, you can specify tokens=1,2,* and then use
for ... %%a in (...) do if %%a==InstallDir set InstallPath=%%c

Answer (score 0):

Where after the reg query did you put it? This should work (look just before the findstr):

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\MySoftware\1.0\MyExecutable /v "InstallDir" 2>NUL ^| findstr InstallDir') do set InstallPath=%%b
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem as his question. The > needs to be escaped using ^.